# How to solve $\frac {\partial f} {\partial y} = xf$ given $f(x,0) = 1 \ \forall x$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations

$f$ is a function of continuous partial derivatives. Find $f$ if:

- $\dfrac {\partial f} {\partial y} = xf$
- $f(x,0) = 1 \ \forall x$

Comment: When you say "fy = xf", do you mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = xf(x,y)$?

Comment: yes this is what i mean

Answer (score 1):

Because $x$ is a constant in the first differential equation, this is just an ordinary one. Now which function has the same derivative? Well that's the exponential. And how to we get this constant $x$ factor? By the chain rule: multiply the $y$ in $e^y$ with $x$: 
$$f(x,y)=e^{xy}$$
Now that we have figured out the function, we can check the boundary condition. To see that it is a solution fill in $y=0$ to see that $f(x,0)=1$.

Comment: can u show me how u solved? I'm new to differentials

Answer (score 0):

Just take a given $x$.  You have $f(x,0)=1, f'(x,y)=xf(x,y)$.  You should be able to solve the second differential equation because you just consider $x$ to be a constant.